# Knockoutjs - Set value in dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

I have a dropdown bound in a field using knockoutjs like this:

```
<select name="CanBePickedUpDropDown" id="CanBePickedUpDropDown" data-bind="value: CanBePickedUp">
    <option selected="selected" value="True">Yes</option>
    <option value="False">No</option>
</select>
```

In my viewmodel, the field looks like this:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.CanBePickedUp = ko.observable("");
}
```

Now I have a Web API that saves the dropdown value to a database. So far, it works. When I select 'No' in the dropdown, it gets save (PUT) in the database as 0 (false). My problem is when it comes to loading. I can't seem to get the dropdown to set the value to 'No'. The Web API looks like this:

```
self.LoadItem = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "Home",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var data = ko.utils.parseJson(result);
            if (data.CanBePickedUp === true)
                self.CanBePickedUp("Yes");
            else
                self.CanBePickedUp.value = "No";
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
        }
    });
};
```

In the above call, data.CanBePickedUp correctly returns false. I'd like to assign it to self.CanBePickedUp so that my dropdown displays 'No' (it alsways displays 'Yes'). I've tried:

```
self.CanBePickedUp.value = "No";
self.CanBePickedUp.value = false;
self.CanBePickedUp("No");
self.CanBePickedUp(false);
```

but none of them worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing it is wrong as per the documentation. Here's how you can achieve the same.

- Create observableArray that has all the possible options
- Create another observable which will hold the active value...

And set the value observable to Yes or no as per requirement

JSFiddle here _ http://jsfiddle.net/5v96a6bp/1/

```
    var viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.canBePickedOptions = ko.observableArray(["Yes","No"]);
        self.selectedOption = ko.observable();

self.LoadItem = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "Home",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var data = ko.utils.parseJson(result);
            if (data.CanBePickedUp === true)
                self.selectedOption("Yes");
            else
                self.selectedOption("No");
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `self.CanBePickedUp("False")`